# Error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written a program to calculate subsidence in the ground after an earthquake. I would like to understand why when I launch the program it tells me as an error: < invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' > at the line "amax = int(ag) * int(ss) * int(st)". Do you know how to solve this problem? Thank you.
The code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Grid, Label, OptionMenu, StringVar, Tk, font, Menu
import tkinter
from tkinter.constants import E, FLAT, W
import math 
                                                                                         
window = tk.Tk()                                                                 
window.geometry("1200x2500")
                                                                                                                     
sedimento_dic = {"Limo":55, "Limo con sabbia":60, "Limo con argilla":65, "Limo 
sabbioso":45, "Limo argilloso":44, "Limo con sabbia argillosa":30, "Limo con sabbia 
debolmente argillosa":70, 
"Limo con argilla sabbiosa":54, "Limo con argilla debolmente sabbiosa":59, 
"Argilla":23, "Argilla con limo":26, "Argilla limosa":51,
"Argilla con sabbia limosa":40, "Argilla con sabbia debolmente limosa":90, "Argilla 
con limo sabbioso":76, "Argilla con limo debolmente sabbioso":11} 

n = None
cedimento = None
risultato_n = None

def calcola_porosità (key):
    n = sedimento_dic.get(key)
risultato_n.configure(text = n)

def calcola_cedimento(spessore, peso_volume, WL, WP, ag, ss, st, vs):
   amax = int(ag) * int(ss) * int(st)
   z = int(spessore) / 2
   peso_volume_eff = int(peso_volume) - 10
   sigma_eff = z * int(peso_volume_eff)
   rd = 1 - (0.015 * z)   

   G_G0 = 0

   if (amax > 0.40):
      G_G0 = 0.28
   else:
       if (amax > 0.30):
          G_G0 = 0.35
       else:
           if (amax > 0.20):
               G_G0 = 0.50
           else:
               if (amax > 0.10):
                   G_G0 = 0.80

  G0 = (int(peso_volume) / 9.81) * pow(vs,2)
  G = int(G_G0) * int(G0)

  gamma_max = 0.65 * (amax / 9.81) * sigma_eff * int(rd) * (1/G)

  if (gamma_max > 0.05):
      ru = 0.2
  else:
      if (gamma_max > 0.10):
          ru = 0.4
      else:
          if (gamma_max > 0.20):
              ru = 0.6
          else:
              if (gamma_max > 0.40):
                ru = 0.8
              else:
                  if (gamma_max > 0.50):
                      ru = 0.95

  e0 = int(n) / (1-int(n))
  IP = int(WL) - int(WP)
  cc = 0.0348 + (0.0162 * IP)
  cr = 0.225 * int(cc)
  ev = (int(cr) / (1 + int(e0))) * (math.log(1 / (1 - ru),10))  

  cedimento = int(ev) * int(spessore)
  cedimento.configure(text = "Il cedimento è pari a: " + int(ev) * int(spessore))
                                                    
spessore_strato_label = tk.Label(window, text="Spessore dello strato")
spessore_strato_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
finestra_spessore = tk.Entry()                                                                        
finestra_spessore.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=20, sticky=W)

sedimento_label = tk.Label(window, text="Sedimento")
sedimento_label.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
variable1 = StringVar(window)
variable1.set(" ")
question_menu1 = OptionMenu(window, variable1, *sedimento_dic, 
command=calcola_porosità)
question_menu1.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, padx=20)

risultato_n=tk.Label(window)
risultato_n.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E)

peso_volume_label = tk.Label(window, text="Peso di volume")
peso_volume_label.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
finestra_peso_volume = tk.Entry()                                                                        
finestra_peso_volume.grid(row=4, column=1)

dati_spt_label = tk.Label(window, text="Dati geotecnici", font=("", 16))
dati_spt_label.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W,pady=15)

WL_label = tk.Label(window, text="Limite liquido")
WL_label.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=W)
finestra_WL = tk.Entry()                                                                        
finestra_WL.grid(row=8, column=1) 

WP_label = tk.Label(window, text="Limite plastico")
WP_label.grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=W)
finestra_WP = tk.Entry()                                                                        
finestra_WP.grid(row=9, column=1)                                                

parametri_sismici_label = tk.Label(window, text="Accelerazione sismica di base")
parametri_sismici_label.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky=W, padx=20)
finestra_ag = tk.Entry()                                                                        
finestra_ag.grid(row=2, column=4)

amplificazione_stratigrafica_label = tk.Label(window, text="Amplificazione 
stratigrafica")
amplificazione_stratigrafica_label.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=W, padx=20)
finestra_ss = tk.Entry()                                                                        
finestra_ss.grid(row=3, column=4)

amplificazione_topografica_label = tk.Label(window, text="Amplificazione 
topografica")
amplificazione_topografica_label.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky=W, padx=20)
finestra_st = tk.Entry()                                                                        
finestra_st.grid(row=4, column=4)


onde_taglio_label = tk.Label(window, text="Velocità delle onde di taglio")
onde_taglio_label.grid(row=5, column=3, sticky=W, padx=20)
finestra_vs = tk.Entry()                                                                        
finestra_vs.grid(row=5, column=4)   

first_button =  tk.Button(text = "Calcola cedimento atteso", command = lambda: 
calcola_cedimento(finestra_spessore.get(),
finestra_peso_volume.get(), finestra_WL.get(), finestra_WP.get(), finestra_ag.get(), 
finestra_ss.get(), finestra_st.get(), finestra_vs.get()))                                                                        
first_button.grid(row=11, column=0) 

cedimento = tk.Label(window)
cedimento.grid(row=12, column=0, sticky=W)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: That is far from __minimal__ reproducible example

Comment: You should take a good look at object types. For example, you first define G0 as a float value (between 0 and 0.80) but then you convert that to an integer in `G = int(G_G0) * int(G0)`. That makes no sense since it converts to 0 every time because int() rounds down. You seem under the impression that you need to call ìnt()` on every object you even use in a calculation, but you only need it once on every strings that the `.get()` method gives you convert it to a number. And you need to figure out whether you want them to be ints or floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5th or 6th or 7th argument passed to `calcola_cedimento` is empty string, i.e. at least one of following returned empty string

```
finestra_ag.get()
finestra_ss.get()
finestra_st.get()
```

If user is allowed to let said entries empty you should provide default values for this case. If for example `ag` value should be `"1"` in such case, you might do

```
ag = "1" if ag=="" else ag
```

before

```
amax = int(ag) * int(ss) * int(st)
```